# Cannot reach the computer in WAN

Tags: router, lan, dhcp, subnet, wan

I wanted to split the internet connection in my room. And my brother also wanted a better wifi accessability. So we bought a router (NETGEAR JWNR2010v5). All we wanted works great, good wifi. I have multiple LAN connections in my room. But now I am unable to reach the computer in the WAN network.

The image illustrates the situation. I do not know to much about networks. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: You will need to set routing rules... although the way you are going about it is not easy... Why do you need two DHCP servers? You are adding an additional headache to your simple setup... It would be easier if you simply turned off DHCP on your JWNR2010 (set its gateway IP to be your B-BOX IP), assign it an IP outside your DHCP scope in your B-BOX and then disable its DHCP server (or if it has the ability to act as an Access Point)... The whole of your network could, in theory, then all obtain IPs in the same range, communicate with each other (sharing resources etc.) and get to the Internet.

Comment: @BigChris I know that one DHCP server would be much better, but i already tried this. If i disable the dhcp server on the jwnr i have no internet access, what do i also have to change? It's local ip?

Comment: Connect your JWNR2010 using one of the LAN ports - NOT the "WAN/Internet" port. Set your JWNR2010 IP address to 192.168.1.64 and subnet 255.255.255.0. Turn off the JWNR2010 DHCP -> save settings -> reboot BOTH routers and your devices should all then be on the same IP range and it all works... For wireless you will need to ensure all the SSID, channel, passphrase, encryption type etc. are all identical so that roaming between the two devices works. Reference: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19852/~/how-do-i-set-up-a-wireless-router-as-an-access-point-on-a-network-that-has

Comment: You'll also need to move the cable running from the B-Box 2 to the JWNR from the blue Internet port and in to a regular port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup you have chosen isn't ideal because you have a number of very different IP ranges and more than one DHCP server on your network. Advanced routing is needed if you wish to continue down this route.

As a solution I (and many others) would recommend you simplify your network considerably by using one DHCP server ("B-BOX" in your diagram), one DHCP pool for all your LAN devices and use your JWNR2010v5 as a simple Access Point by disabling its DHCP server.

By default, a consumer grade router (whether wireless, ethernet or both) has a built-in DHCP server that provides addresses to LAN devices connected to it. If you introduce such a router to a network that already has an existing DHCP server (such as your "B-BOX") then the DHCP servers will conflict and you will [ultimately] have no network connectivity between the two routers.

Disabling the DHCP server on the additional router will cause any connected devices to obtain IP addresses from the existing DHCP server on the network.

With this background knowledge we can resolve the problems you are experiencing.

One thing you need to remedy from your diagram:

> You have connected your JWNR2010v5 "WAN/Internet" (blue socket) to
>   your B-BOX - you must not connect the additional router to your
>   network using the "WAN/internet" port. Plug it into one of the
>   standard LAN ports at the back of the JWNR2010v5.

Resolution:

1. Connect a computer (by Ethernet) to your JWNR2010v5 and log on to its admin pages
2. Go to the LAN setup pages where you can control LAN addressing such as DHCP
3. Set your JWNR2010v5 device to have an address outside of your B-BOX DHCP range but within the subnet your B-BOX is using for LAN devices. **For your scenario 192.168.1.64** should be suitable
4. Set your JWNR2010v5 device to have a subnet mask the same as your B-BOX router: **255.255.255.0**
5. **Disable the DHCP server** on your JWNR2010v5
6. Save the settings
7. Whilst on the JWNR2010v5 admin pages configure your wireless network to have precisely the same SSID, channel, encryption and passphrase as your B-BOX - this will ensure any wireless devices on your network will seamlessly connect to whichever router is nearest.
8. Save the settings
9. **Restart BOTH routers**
10. Once both routers have restarted you should notice your LAN devices obtain new IP addresses in the 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.63 range and they should all be able to browse the internet and communicate internally (file/print sharing etc.)

Using the following reference for a newer Netgear router: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19852/~/how-do-i-set-up-a-wireless-router-as-an-access-point-on-a-network-that-has

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what's going on here. <sub>(Now that I've got some coffee in me...)</sub>

Network Address Translation, or NAT, is what's getting in the way. NAT is meant to take your public IP address, the one provided by your ISP, and essentially turn it in to a private network.

The Internet sees your public IP address. To web servers, it's all the same. Your router sorts out where to send the data:

[image]

So when we add another router, which performs NAT, we end up 'hiding' our second private network. Your first router doesn't know where to send the packets, and the second router is treating everything on our first network like the Big Bad Internet:

[image]

And while your `10.0.0.101` *may* be able to connect to PCs on your first network (the `192.168.0.0` network), we're also going to be dropping broadcasts, which is going to break your Sharing, Windows Workgroups, and NetBIOS over TCP (NBT) goodies. This is why you can't 'see' the other PC when you open up Network from Explorer:

[image]

So, how do we fix it?

#### Set your Router to Bridge Mode

The simplest way is to have the router function as a wireless access point and switch, rather than a router. This is often called **Bridge Mode** in your router's configuration page. This will shut off NAT (and hopefully DHCP, but do check) and allow your 'Internet' port to function as a normal switch port. No more network segregation.

On your second router...

1. Go to your router's configuration page
2. Find the Internet settings
3. Set to Bridge Mode
4. Ensure DHCP is disabled
5. Set a static IP address within your first router's subnet, but outside DHCP
6. Reboot your routers
7. Reboot your PCs, or open a command prompt and run `ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew`

#### Bypass the Internet port

From what I can see however, this particular router doesn't support Bridge Mode. What you can do is 'trick' it by hooking your second router up to the first using a normal port, rather than an Internet port.

The only problem we have now is DHCP. Your second router is still going to be saying, "Come to me for Internet!" It doesn't have a connection to the Internet, your first router does. So while you can likely see the other computers on your network now, there's still some routing issues and a lack of Internet connectivity:

[image]

By disabling DHCP, we allow the first router to handle the entire network. We also avoid a whole host of problems that come with having two DHCP servers.

Our second router is left to sit out in the rain, like that weird kid that nobody will play with at recess. But we might need it again, and it's going to be a real pain to connect to it if it's sitting on a different subnet. So first you're going to want to set a static address within your first router's subnet (`192.168.0.x`) but outside its DHCP range (We don't want any collisions! Check your configuration or the manual for the range.)

[image]

1. Take the cable in the Internet port and plug it in to a regular port
2. Shut off DHCP
3. Change to a static IP within your first router's subnet, but outside DHCP
4. Reboot your routers
5. Reboot your PCs, or open a command prompt and run `ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew`

This is somewhat simplified and probably a little inaccurate, but hopefully this illustrates the problems you're experiencing and how to fix them.

Comment: I bet computers do actually talk to each other like that... under all that binary is "1: Hey bro, you put weight on? 0: At least I'm not stick thin like you! 0: Yeah, leave us chubby zeros alone! 1: HaaaHa!"